# Find $f(z)$ given the modulus

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

The analytic function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, $\ f(z)=u+iv \ $ with the property that $$|f(z)|=\varphi\left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{x}\right)$$

where $\varphi$ is a function depending on $\frac{x^2+y^2}{x}$

Any hint to solve this? I don't need a complete solution.

Thanks!

Comment: What is $\varphi$?

Comment: The modululs of the function $f$ depends on a general function $\varphi(\frac{x^2+y^2}{x})$

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're saying is that the curves $|f(z)|=constant$ have the form $\dfrac{x^2 + y^2}{x} = constant$ (at least for $x \ne 0$: I don't know what you want to happen for $x=0$). Such curves (as you see from multiplying by $x$ and completing the square) are circles passing through the origin.  But there are problems with that: $|f(0)|$ can only be one number.  Thus the answer to the question
as stated is that $f$ must be constant: any nonconstant $f$ couldn't be analytic at $0$.

On the other hand, if $f$ is allowed to be analytic on $\mathbb C \backslash \{0\}$ you can have solutions

$f(z) = e^{c/z}$ for real constants $c$.

Comment: $|f(z)|$ could be, for instance, $|f(z)|=\sin(\frac{x^2+y^2}{x})\cdot\left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{x}\right)$ so it's not necessary $\frac{x^2+y^2}{x}$ to be constant constant. This is what I'm thinking.

Comment: @EmM1500 So what could $f(0)$ be in that case?  Or, for that matter, $f(i)$?